# Show link to reset OTP device in keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, google-authenticator

I would like to provide the user with the option to reset their OTP device in case it is lost or stolen. I know there is the option in the console to reset it, but I am looking for something that can be more self service, instead of contacting the administrators.
Does anyone have any suggestions about how to implement this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, enable "Forgot Password" in "Realm Setting -> Login"

Then edit the theme, specifically the login page and override login/messages/messages_en.properties "doForgotPassword=", with whatever wording you'd like "OTP Reset", etc. That's the text of the link that will show up on the login page.

Theming is kinda wonky in Keycloak. So you might have to dig around a bit to learn how that works first.